# Nim - How to access mytype of a field that has the type Option[mytype] at compile time?

Tags: generics, nim-lang

Heyho,

While coding my way through some generics I stumbled upon an issue with one of my generic functions.
I have 2 types such as this

```
import std/options
import norm

type
    A = ref object of Model
        name: string
    B = ref object of Model
        name: string
        myA: Option[A]
```

[norm](https://norm.nim.town/), an ORM in nim for sqlite, has the capability for me to grab the sql-tablename a model belongs to at compile time by just having a type that inherits from Model and calling `table()` on it.

For various reasons I want to be able to figure out the name of all tables, that a given Model links to. In this case, `B` links to the type `A`, but I need to call `A.table()` to get that tablename at compile-time (which could be anything if the `{.tableName.}` pragma is in use).

However, I can't seem to find a way to access my type, since I can't call the typical `get()` method of the `options` module at compile time. What is my way out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the immensely helpful folks at the nim-discord server (shoutout to leorize there) I was able to solve this issue. In fact, I only made this question so I can google the answer easier myself.

There are multiple ways of going about this:

1. Try to access the type directly

The generic parameter of `Option` is called `T`. Within that `T` is the type that you're looking for.

```
proc getRelatedFieldName[M: Model, O:Model](targetType: typedesc[O], sourceType: typedesc[M]): Option[string] =
    let source = sourceType()
    for sourceFieldName, sourceFieldValue in source[].fieldPairs:
        when sourceFieldValue is Option:
            when sourceFieldValue.get() is Model:
                when O.table() == sourceFieldValue.T.table():
                    return some(sourceFieldName) 

    return none(string)


echo A.getRelatedFieldName(B) # returns "some('myA')"
```

If you do this with not a typedesc but actual types, you may want to consider using `typeof(sourceFieldValue).T.table()` instead.

2. Use `typetrait`'s `genericParams` function

You can use the `[typetraits][1]` library and its [genericParams](https://nim-lang.org/docs/typetraits.html#genericParams.t%2Ctypedesc) function.

`genericParams(B).get(0)`

With genericParams as a tool you can then do interesting things, like iterating over all fields of a type (not an instance!) at compile time, check whether a given field is an Option of a Model and compare tablenames

```
proc getRelatedFieldName[M: Model, O:Model](targetType: typedesc[O], sourceType: typedesc[M]): Option[string] =
    let source = sourceType()
    for sourceFieldName, sourceFieldValue in source[].fieldPairs:
        when sourceFieldValue is Option:
            when sourceFieldValue.get() is Model:
                when O.table() == genericParams(sourceFieldValue.type()).get(0).table():
                    return some(sourceFieldName) 

    return none(string)


echo A.getRelatedFieldName(B) # returns "some('myA')"
```