# Nim - Norm - How to get related fieldnames at compile time

Tags: generics, compile-time, nim-lang

Heyho,

I am using [norm](https://norm.nim.town/), an orm in the nim programming language.
I have 2 different models such as this:

```
import std/options
import norm

type
    A {.tableName: "Surprise".} = ref object of Model
        name: string

    Surprise = ref object of Model
        name: string
        anotherFieldThatExistsOnTheSQLTableButNotOnA: int

    B = ref object of Model
        name: string
        myA: Option[A]
```

I want to be able to figure out at compile time the name of a given foreign key-field (here `myA`) that points to a given table (here `Surprise`) even if the model has a different name than the actual table or is a read-only model (e.g. A). That way I can write SQL queries at compile time that get me the many of a many-to-one relationship.

More importantly, I want this grabbing of the foreign-key relationship to be based upon the `tableName` of a model, not the model itself. Thus, if I were to define a proc `getRelatedFieldName(startType: typedesc[A], otherType: typedesc[B])`, it would need to give the same result for both `getRelatedFieldName(A, B)` AND `getRelatedFieldName(A, Surprise)`.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to some hints of the very helpful folks at the nim discord server, I was able to write the solution.

The answer is: Nim's generics, Nim's `getCustomPragmaVal` macro and Norm's `table` template.

The below code takes 2 model-types. It dummy-instantiates the `sourceType` since that's the type that potentially has a foreignKey-field to your `targetType`. It then iterates over the fields of `sourceType` and checks whether they are either directly a Model type, are annotated with an `fk` aka foreignKey pragma, or are an `Option[Model]` type.

If the field has a `Model` type, the issue is solved since you can just call `Model.table()` and you're done. If the field has an `fk` pragma, you can simply call `getCustomPragmaVal` to get the Model that this field is a foreign key for. With that you have the type and can just call `table()` on that. Lastly, you may have an `Option[Model]` type. In that case you need to extract the generic parameters using the [genericParams](https://nim-lang.org/docs/typetraits.html#genericParams.t%2Ctypedesc) function (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70628041/nim-how-to-access-mytype-of-a-field-that-has-the-type-optionmytype-at-compil)). That way you can, once again, access the type and call `table()` on that.

```
proc getRelatedFieldName[M: Model, O:Model](targetType: typedesc[O], sourceType: typedesc[M]): Option[string] =
    let source = sourceType()
    for sourceFieldName, sourceFieldValue in source[].fieldPairs:
        #Handles case where field is an int64 with fk pragma
        when sourceFieldValue.hasCustomPragma(fk):
            when O.table() == sourceFieldValue.getCustomPragmaVal(fk).table():
                return some(sourceFieldName)
        
        #Handles case where field is a Model type
        when sourceFieldValue is Model:
            when O.table() == sourceFieldValue.type().table():
                return some(sourceFieldName)
        
        #Handles case where field is a Option[Model] type
        when sourceFieldValue is Option:
            when sourceFieldValue.get() is Model:
                when O.table() == genericParams(sourceFieldValue.type()).get(0).table():
                    return some(sourceFieldName) 

    return none(string)
```

example

```
type
    A = ref object of Model # <-- has implicit tableName "A"
        name: string
    AC {.tableName: "A".} = ref object of Model
        myothername: string
        name: string

    B = ref object of Model # <-- has implicit tableName "B"
        name: string
        myA: Option[A]
    D = ref object of Model
        myothernameid: int
        myDA: A
    E = ref object of Model
        myotherbool: bool
        myEA {.fk: A.}: int64

    
echo A.getRelatedFieldName(B) # some("myA")
echo AC.getRelatedFieldName(B) # some("myA")
echo A.getRelatedFieldName(D) # some("myDA")
echo AC.getRelatedFieldName(D) # some("myDA")
echo A.getRelatedFieldName(E) # some("myEA")
echo AC.getRelatedFieldName(E) # some("myEA")
```